# Can't make driver for AWUS036ACH

Tags: linux, openwrt

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and I need to create an image of an openwrt-based system with support for AWUS036ACH.
I have completed the following steps:

1. Created his own package for buildroot tools, the makefile of which contains a "Build/Compile" section:

```
define Build/Compile
        @echo "-----------------"
        @echo "CC=$(TARGET_CC)"
        @echo "-----------------"
        $(MAKE) $(PKG_JOBS) -C "$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)" \
                CC="$(TARGET_CC)" \
                KERNEL_SOURCE="$(LINUX_DIR)" \
                TARGET_CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS)" \
                TARGET_LDFLAGS="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS)" \
                M="$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)"
endef
```

2. I downloaded the driver sources from https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/ and made changes to their Makefile:

```
modules:
        $(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CC=$(CC) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KERNEL_SOURCE) M=$(M) LDFLAGS="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS)" CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS)" modules
        @echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        @echo "Visit https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au for support/reporting issues"
        @echo "or check for newer versions (branches) of these drivers.                   "
        @echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

However, when I start building the system, I get an error:

```
make -j1 -C "/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0" CC="aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc" KERNEL_SOURCE="/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/linux-5.4.31" TARGET_CFLAGS="-Os -pipe -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -fhonour-copts -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-result -ffile-prefix-map=/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0=Alfa-WiFi-1.0 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro" TARGET_LDFLAGS="-L/home/aleks/openwrt/source/staging_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/usr/lib -L/home/aleks/openwrt/source/staging_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/lib -L/home/aleks/openwrt/source/staging_dir/toolchain-aarch64_cortex-a72_gcc-8.4.0_musl/usr/lib -L/home/aleks/openwrt/source/staging_dir/toolchain-aarch64_cortex-a72_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib -znow -zrelro" M="/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0"
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0'
make ARCH=arm64 CC=aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc CROSS_COMPILE= -C /home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/linux-5.4.31 M=/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0 LDFLAGS="-L/home/aleks/openwrt/source/staging_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/usr/lib -L/home/aleks/openwrt/source/staging_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/lib -L/home/aleks/openwrt/source/staging_dir/toolchain-aarch64_cortex-a72_gcc-8.4.0_musl/usr/lib -L/home/aleks/openwrt/source/staging_dir/toolchain-aarch64_cortex-a72_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib -znow -zrelro" CFLAGS="-Os -pipe -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -fhonour-copts -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-result -ffile-prefix-map=/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0=Alfa-WiFi-1.0 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro" modules
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/linux-5.4.31'
arch/arm64/Makefile:27: ld does not support --fix-cortex-a53-843419; kernel may be susceptible to erratum
  CC [M]  /home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0/core/rtw_security.o
....
....
  CC [M]  /home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0/core/rtw_mp.o
  LD [M]  /home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0/88XXau.o
ld: unrecognised emulation mode: aarch64linux
Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu i386linux elf_l1om elf_k1om i386pep i386pe
scripts/Makefile.build:437: recipe for target '/home/aleks/openwrt/source/build_dir/target-aarch64_cortex-a72_musl/linux-bcm27xx_bcm2711/Alfa-WiFi-1.0/88XXau.o' failed
```

Help me, please!

Comment: I removed the "buildroot" tag as the question is about OpenWRT, not Buildroot. OpenWRT forked from Buildroot 10+ years ago and is now completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you are using the host toolchain (at least ld).
Your CROSS_COMPILE option is empty.

have you take a look at https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_packages_building_kernel_modules